# IOException after thousands of socket creation calls

Tags: java, sockets, ioexception

Why `IOException` after thousands of socket creation calls?

I did a simple Server code (Java) which accepts connections then creates a thread reads the socket and sends back another character to the Client
The Client code starts to do a cycling (long enough to reproduce the issue) and in each cycle creates 50 threads in each thread creating a client socket to server machine and sends a character then reads from socket the character that the Server sends back. 
Then both the Client and the Server closes the socket.

After a while I notice that on Client side I get exception in client socket creation.
Are there some limitations which I should take in consideration to work this properly or this should work in an infinite loop?

I'm thinking here to situations that maybe after a long enough cycling time the client side tries to bind the new socket to a port on client machine which is still binded to a socket which is in CLOSED state but that time period which needs to be elapsed to be freed by kernel not passed yet. (sorry don't know official name of this time period)
The client and server machines are two Linux systems in VMware.

Comment: _what_ IOException...?  and yes, you are most likely using up all available ports before they can be freed up.  what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like maybe your connection was dropped.

You forgot rule #1 in the [Fallacies of Distributed Computing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacies_of_Distributed_Computing): The network is always reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the `setReuseAddress` parameter to true on your ServerSocket? If not, you have to wait a quite long time before the kernel release network resources.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you !
Actually this is my Server side code

```
public class TestServer {

  public void createThread() {
    System.out.println("createThread");
    ServerThread servThread = new ServerThread();
    servThread.start();   
  }

  public static final void main(String[] args) {

    ServerSocket server = null;

    try {
      System.out.println("Started");
      server = new ServerSocket(12345);
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {
      System.out.println("Server: Exception at socket creation: " + ex.getMessage());
    }

    try {
      while(true) {
        Socket clientSock = server.accept();
        System.out.println("Connection Accepted: server: "+clientSock.getLocalPort()+", Client: "+clientSock.getPort());
        ServerThread servThread = new ServerThread(clientSock);
        servThread.start();
      }
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {
      System.out.println("Server: Exception at socket accept: " + ex.getMessage());
    }

  }
}

class ServerThread extends Thread {

  private Socket sock;

  public ServerThread() {}

  public ServerThread(Socket sock) {
    this.sock = sock;
  }

  public void run() {
    InputStream is = null;
    OutputStream os = null;
    try {
      is = sock.getInputStream();
      os = sock.getOutputStream();
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {}  

    try {     
      int b = is.read();
      System.out.println("server: received = " + (char)b);
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {
      System.out.println("Server: IOException at read = " + ex.getMessage());
    }

    try {
      os.write('R');
      os.flush();
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {
      System.out.println("Server: IOException at write = " + ex.getMessage());
    }

    try {
      sock.close();
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {
      System.out.println("Server: IOException at close = " + ex.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

and this is the Client part:

```
public class TestClient {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    if (args.length != 4) {
      System.out.println("Usage: java TestClient <ServerIP> <nbThreads> <cycle> <delay>");
      System.exit(1);
    }

    String host   = args[0];
    int nbThreads = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    int cycle     = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
    int delay     = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);

    for (int i = 0; i<cycle; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j<nbThreads; j++) {
        ClientThread clThread = new ClientThread(host);
        clThread.start();
      }
/*      try {
        Thread.sleep(delay);
      }
      catch (Exception ex) {} */
    }
  }
}

class ClientThread extends Thread {

  private String host;

  public ClientThread(String host) {
    this.host = host;
  }

  public void run(){

    for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
      Socket clientSock = null;
      try {
        clientSock = new Socket(host, 12345);
      }
      catch(IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Client: IOException at socket creation = " + ex.getMessage());
      }

      OutputStream os = null;
      InputStream  is = null;
      try {
        os = clientSock.getOutputStream();
        is = clientSock.getInputStream();
      }
      catch (IOException ex) { }

      try {
        os.write('B');
        os.flush();
      }
      catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Client: IOException at write = " + ex.getMessage());
      }

      try {
        int reply = is.read();
        System.out.println("Client: reply = " + (char)reply);
      }
      catch(IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Client: IOException at read = " + ex.getMessage());
      }

      try {
        clientSock.close();
      }
      catch(IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Client: IOException at close = " + ex.getMessage());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm testing with 60 threads and 1000 cycle and no delay.

I was wrong in my first question, the exception comes from the is.read() call after a while and it is 'Connection reset' exception.
I did this sample code to simulate the problem I'm getting in my application code where I'm getting the exception during the client socket creation ... but it seems I need to find further what is the difference netween this and my application code.
However I think would help me also to understand why after a while I'm getting the 'Connection reset' exception on the client side after a while. 
Is that possible that on the server side once os.write('R') happened the sock.close() happens so fast that on the client side the is.read() call hasn't reached yet. Sound strange :)

Also not sure on which socket I should use the setReuseAddress function. Isn't on the client side, because there I'm creating again and again the sockets... although now I'm not getting the exception at client socket creation.
Thanks !